# How do I disable 8139too network driver in favor of the 8139cp network driver in Ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu, networking, drivers

I'm trying to disable the `8139too` network driver in favor of the `8139cp` driver on my Ubuntu 8.04 server. The current driver crashes when the network card exceeds about 1 MB/s.

The `syslog` also recommends switching to 8139cp:

```
8139too: Use the "8139cp" driver for improved performance and stability.
```

I've added `blacklist 8139too` to `/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist` but that doesn't seem to have any effect.

Is there some other way to switch network drivers that I'm not aware of?

Comment: ¿Can you post the line you add to the /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist, please?

Comment: @Brigo He did already!

Comment: [Ubuntu 8.04 will reach end of life in April 2013.](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Releases) Your time will probably be better spent upgrading the server's OS.

Comment: I'm quite aware of that, but there are an unknown set of legacy services on that box. The distro-upgrade will have to wait.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am going to assume you already have the `8139too` and `8139cp` modules on the machine, and you just want to swap the `8139too` with the `8139cp` driver. Please note you can easily lock yourself out of the server using this method, so be careful.

Firstly run an `lsmod` and check what modules the `mii` module depends on e.g:

`:~# lsmod | grep 8139

8139too 38400  0

8139cp 34944  0

mii 14720  2 8139too,8139cp`

As you can see the `mii` module depends on both of the `8139` modules. Now that we know which modules `mii` depends on we can unload the all the modules, reload the module we want and restart our networking. Here is what we are going to do:

`rmmod 8139cp

rmmod 8139too

rmmod mii

modprobe 8139cp

modprobe mii

service networking restart`

Short explanation of the code above. First three line remove the offending modules, then with `modprobe` we add the modules we want. In this case it will be the `8139cp` and `mii` modules, restart your networking and use `ethtool` to check that it is working properly.

`:~# ethtool -i eth0

driver: 8139cp

version: 1.3

firmware-version:

bus-info: 0000:00:12.0`

This is a small workaround and will reset once you restart the server, to make it permanent create a bash script with the code above and add it to your startup scripts.